# Which data structure should I use to handle multi value data?

Tags: java, data-structures

I started working on an investing  project in java and I need a good data-structure to meet its requirements. I've seen some solutions here to a bit similar questions, but with different requirements.

My requirements are as follow:

1. A Company object has a symbol, company name, sector, and financial data fields.
2. Searching for a specific company requires a symbol or a company name.

First, I thought about creating a map with symbol as the key and company name as the value (for simplicity assume I harvest the data from here:
http://data.okfn.org/data/core/s-and-p-500-companies/r/constituents.csv  ), but then I had a second thought because symbol and company name are both Company object data fields, so maybe it's not the best solution OO-wise. Plus, remember it also requires something like a vlookup capability so companies can be found not just by using their symbol but also their name.

What's the best DS to meet my requirements ? 
`map<String Symbol, Company company>` is good for this purpose?

A few notes:

Assume I also want to have all the data in my program and not just searching for it on the web.

There're 500 objects in this DS, though companies can be added or removed.

The solution should be so searching for  all the companies from a specific sector (or other data - like all companies with a market cap higher than 100 B$, etc) will be  easy to implement, and efficient.

I don't know if the user enter a symbol or a company name.

The data will also be saved to a file.

The solution should use java core only (not commons, guava etc).

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a persistent storage? If you use in-memory storage only, all your changes like adding of removing companies will be lost when the application crashes or is shut down.

Comment: Yes I do, I forgot mentioning that

Comment: And you are sure that you don't want to use a database?

Comment: Not for now. Maybe later I'll consider it. For now I want to work just with java DS.

Comment: Would you consider using 2 maps, one keyed on symbol and the other keyed on company name?

Comment: @LucasS. Persistent DS is  not a necessity for the beginning.

Comment: @vikingsteve - That could work. Though it's not so efficient space-wise. 500 is not much, but maybe I'll work someday with 5000 entries and not just 500. Maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the space of a map. It's essentially just a set of keys and object references. Having 2 maps doesn't mean your domain object will be duplicated - just the reference.

Comment: @vikingsteve - true.  Plus I don't know if the I should look for a symbol or a name, so I need to check both (unless I ask the user if he's interested in searching for a symbol or a name), so your solution won't have any impact on search efficiency. Though updating the data would require twice the  time in comparison to one DS so it's probably not the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use Java classes only, using two Maps is the best option here. While it does need two operations to store a single new company, you will probably read data way more often than you store it. And as long as it's stored as references the additional space required by a second Map is negligible.

However, in the unlikely case that there is a deteministic way to create a company's symbol out of it's name or vice versa, it would be possible to create a hash function which calculates identical hashes for a company's symbol and name. In that case a HashTable/HashMap would be slighlty more efficient.

---

**Sidenote:**

Since you already save your data to a file, which is a kind of persistent storage, I recommend using a database. The sole purpose of a DBMS is to store, manage and query large amounts of data efficiently making them the best option in most situations. And with Java's SQL libraries `java.sql.*` it's really easy to integrate as well.

Comment: I haven't found a better solution yet, probably creating two map is unavoidable. Thanks. You're right, there's no deterministic way to know what's the symbol by company's name and vise versa, otherwise a hash function would solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe after doing it just by using java classes I'll use java's sql library.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the symbol or the company name given exactly when you search, you could use a `Map` where you enter each company twice. Once with the symbol as key and once with the name as key.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a database, then it would be much easier. No need to create a map to hold all the Company objects in memory. Persist all the Company objects as rows into the database, with may be symbol as the primary key. This makes searching with symbols straight. Then you can index the database table for company name column, which will make querying with company name also straight. Though, it will take more space and time for insert operations, read operations will be much faster. Similarly, you can create index for other fields/columns like market cap, according to which the companies are often queried. Rather than writing the logic to query the company objects as per different fields, you can leave this work to the database and just query the database for what you want.